# if i use root.setFocusableInTouchMode(true) in fragment setHasOptionsMenu(true) is not working

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, fragment

in my fragment below

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout1, null);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    activity = getActivity();
```

the menu function is working until i add a onKeyListener. after i add onKeyListener, menu not working!!

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout1, null);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    activity = getActivity();
    root.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    root.requestFocus();
    root.setOnKeyListener(onKey);
 .
 .
 .
 .
 OnKeyListener onKey = new OnKeyListener() {

    public boolean onKey(View arg0, int keyCode, KeyEvent arg2) {

    }
}
```

What is the solution to work both in fragment?

Answer (score 0):

did you tested to call setHasOptionsMenu within your onCreate ?

```
@Override
public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}
```